# StopWatch on Tkinter ...Creating a Class

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I used [this link](http://ygchan.blogspot.com/2012/05/python-stop-watch-timer-source-code.html) as inspiration. My question is how I can rewrite this code into a class. I'm very new with classes and I'm trying to understand where I need to use (self) and where I don't through an example.

## Stop Watch on Tkinter

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
timeFrame = LabelFrame(root, text='Time Frame', width=1200)
timeFrame.grid(row=2,column=2, sticky=W)

timer = [0,0,0] # [minutes ,seconds, centiseconds]

def update_time():
    if (state):
        global timer
        timer[2] += 1

        if (timer[2] >= 100):   #100 centiseconds --> 1 second
            timer[2] = 0
            timer[1] += 1       #add 1 second

        if (timer[1] >= 60):    #60 seconds --> 1 minute
            timer[0] += 1
            timer[1] = 0

        timeString = str(timer[0]) + ':' + str(timer[1]) + ':' + str(timer[2])
        show.config(text=timeString)
    root.after(10, update_time)

def start():
    global state
    state = True
    print 'Clock Running...'

def pause():
    global state
    state = False
    timeString = str(timer[0]) + ':' + str(timer[1]) + ':' + str(timer[2])
    timeList.insert(END, timeString)
    print 'Clock Paused'    

def resetTime():
    global timer
    timer = [0,0,0]
    print 'Clock is Reset'  
    show.config(text='00:00:00')


state = False

resetButton = Button(timeFrame, text='Reset', command=resetTime)
resetButton.grid(row=2,column=1)

pauseButton = Button(timeFrame, text='Pause', command=pause)
pauseButton.grid(row=1,column=1)

startButton = Button(timeFrame, text='Start', command=start)
startButton.grid(row=0,column=1)

show = Label(timeFrame, text='00:00:00', font=('Helvetica', 30))
show.grid(row=0, column=0)

timeList = Listbox(timeFrame, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
timeList.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=3)

# Quit Button
quit = Button(timeFrame, text='QUIT', command=quit)
quit.grid(row=3, column=1)
update_time()

root.mainloop()
```

The code above works with a "small heartbeat" on python 3.5.0
Can anyone help me understand how to translate this code into a class??

Here is my best try at doing what I want:

Error: Stopwatch instance has no attribute 'running' - Line 48

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

root = Tkinter.Tk()

# running = False

class Stopwatch(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.widgets()
        self.update_time()
        self.running = False
        self.update_time()
        self.timer = [0,0,0]    # [minutes ,seconds, centiseconds]
        self.timeString = str(self.timer[0]) + ':' + str(self.timer[1]) + ':' + str(self.timer[2])

    def widgets(self):
        self.timeFrame = LabelFrame(root, text='Time Frame', width=1200)
        self.timeFrame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W)

        self.resetButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Reset', command=self.resetTime)
        self.resetButton.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.pauseButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Pause', command=self.pause)
        self.pauseButton.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.startButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Start', command=self.start)
        self.startButton.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.show = Label(self.timeFrame, text='00:00:00', font=('Helvetica', 30))
        self.show.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Quit Button
        self.quit = Button(self.timeFrame, text='QUIT', command=self.quit)
        self.quit.grid(row=3, column=1)


    def update_time(self):

        if (self.running == True):      #Clock is running

            self.timer[2] += 1

            if (self.timer[2] >= 100):  #100 centiseconds --> 1 second
                self.timer[2] = 0
                self.timer[1] += 1      #add 1 second

            if (self.timer[1] >= 60):   #60 seconds --> 1 minute
                self.timer[0] += 1
                self.timer[1] = 0

            self.timeString = str(timer[0]) + ':' + str(timer[1]) + ':' + str(timer[2])
            self.show.config(text=timeString)
        root.after(10, update_time)


    def start(self):            #Start the clock
        global running
        running = True
        print 'Clock Running...'

    def pause(self):            #Pause the clock
        global running
        running = False
        print 'Clock Paused'    

    def resetTime(self):        #Reset the clock
        global timer
        running = False
        self.timer = [0,0,0]
        print 'Clock is Reset'  
        self.show.config(text='00:00:00')

    def quit(self):             #Quit the program
        root.destroy()



watch = Stopwatch(root)

root.mainloop()
```

***Ok, here is my fixed Stopwatch program...This one works***

```
import random
import math
import turtle
import time
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *

root = Tkinter.Tk()

# running = False

class Stopwatch(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.widgets()
        self.running = False
        self.timer = [0,0,0]    # [minutes ,seconds, centiseconds]
        self.timeString = str(self.timer[0]) + ':' + str(self.timer[1]) + ':' + str(self.timer[2])
        self.update_time()

    def widgets(self):
        self.timeFrame = LabelFrame(root, text='Time Frame', width=1200)
        self.timeFrame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W)

        self.resetButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Reset', command=self.resetTime)
        self.resetButton.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.pauseButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Pause', command=self.pause)
        self.pauseButton.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.startButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Start', command=self.start)
        self.startButton.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.show = Label(self.timeFrame, text='00:00:00', font=('Helvetica', 30))
        self.show.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Quit Button
        self.quit = Button(self.timeFrame, text='QUIT', command=self.quit)
        self.quit.grid(row=3, column=1)


    def update_time(self):

        if (self.running == True):      #Clock is running

            self.timer[2] += 1

            if (self.timer[2] >= 100):  #100 centiseconds --> 1 second
                self.timer[2] = 0
                self.timer[1] += 1      #add 1 second

            if (self.timer[1] >= 60):   #60 seconds --> 1 minute
                self.timer[0] += 1
                self.timer[1] = 0

            self.timeString = str(self.timer[0]) + ':' + str(self.timer[1]) + ':' + str(self.timer[2])
            self.show.config(text=self.timeString)
        root.after(10, self.update_time)


    def start(self):            #Start the clock
        self.running = True
        print 'Clock Running...'

    def pause(self):            #Pause the clock
        self.running = False
        print 'Clock Paused'    

    def resetTime(self):        #Reset the clock
        self.running = False
        self.timer = [0,0,0]
        print 'Clock is Reset'  
        self.show.config(text='00:00:00')

    def quit(self):             #Quit the program
        root.destroy()



watch = Stopwatch(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: timer, state, show and timeString should be class variables (= self. ...) => anything you need to access in functions.

Comment: You can also make a class Timer with three integer fields, a state variable, and three functions increment, reset and displayAsString functions...

Comment: I've posted my best attempt for the class Stopwatch...it is posted above. I'm not sure how to fix it but I have the following error: "global name 'update_time' is not defined". Can anyone help me get it working and fix my errors?

Comment: That's a good start. `root.after(10, update_time)` should be `root.after(10, self.update_time)` Also replace remaining `running` and `timer` by `self.running` and `self.timer`. `self.update_time()` should be after self.running = False...

Comment: Eric, thank you for your help...this program works however no one has asked my other question about when and when not to assign (self)...in this example, self was assigned to all the pieces (running, timer, timeString, etc). Is it always the case to assign (self) to ALL objects?

Comment: You should use `self` for all objects that are used in at least two functions (usually, one of them is `__init__` - or a function called by `__init__`) 
You don't need it for the others (but it will work if you use it). For example, resetButton doesn't *need* it. 
Always be careful to use it everywhere or nowhere for a given object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final product...it contains a stopwatch (counts up) and timer (counts down).

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *


# This program is designed to count up from zero
class CountsUp(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.widgets()
        self.running = False
        self.timer = [0,0,0]    # [minutes ,seconds, centiseconds]
        self.timeString = str(self.timer[0]) + ':' + str(self.timer[1]) + ':' + str(self.timer[2])
        self.update_time()

    def widgets(self):
        self.timeFrame = LabelFrame(root, text='Counts Up')
        self.timeFrame.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=W)

        self.resetButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Reset', command=self.resetTime)
        self.resetButton.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.pauseButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Pause', command=self.pause)
        self.pauseButton.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.startButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Start', command=self.start)
        self.startButton.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.show = Label(self.timeFrame, text='00:00:00', font=('Helvetica', 30))
        self.show.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.quit = Button(self.timeFrame, text='QUIT', command=self.quit)
        self.quit.grid(row=3, column=1)


    def update_time(self):

        if (self.running == True):      #Clock is running

            self.timer[2] += 1          #Count Down

            if (self.timer[2] >= 100):  #100 centiseconds --> 1 second
                self.timer[2] = 0       #reset to zero centiseconds
                self.timer[1] += 1      #add 1 second

            if (self.timer[1] >= 60):   #60 seconds --> 1 minute
                self.timer[0] += 1      #add 1 minute
                self.timer[1] = 0       #reset to 0 seconds

            self.timeString = str(self.timer[0]) + ':' + str(self.timer[1]) + ':' + str(self.timer[2])
            self.show.config(text=self.timeString)
        root.after(10, self.update_time)

    def start(self):            #Start the clock
        self.running = True
        print 'Clock Running...'

    def pause(self):            #Pause the clock
        self.running = False
        print 'Clock Paused'    

    def resetTime(self):        #Reset the clock
        self.running = False
        self.timer = [0,0,0]
        print 'Clock is Reset'  
        self.show.config(text='00:00:00')

    def quit(self):             #Quit the program
        root.destroy()



# This program is designed to count down from a starting time
class CountsDown(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.widgets()
        self.running = False
        self.timer = [0,0,0]    # [minutes ,seconds, centiseconds]
        self.timeString = str(self.timer[0]) + ':' + str(self.timer[1]) + ':' + str(self.timer[2])
        self.update_time()

    def widgets(self):
        self.timeFrame = LabelFrame(root, text='Counts Down')
        self.timeFrame.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=W)

        self.resetButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Reset', command=self.resetTime)
        self.resetButton.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.pauseButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Pause', command=self.pause)
        self.pauseButton.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.startButton = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Start', command=self.start)
        self.startButton.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.show = Label(self.timeFrame, text='00:00:00', font=('Helvetica', 30))
        self.show.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.addMinute = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Add Minute', command=self.addMinute)
        self.addMinute.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.addSecond = Button(self.timeFrame, text='Add Second', command=self.addSecond)
        self.addSecond.grid(row=3,column=0)

        self.quit = Button(self.timeFrame, text='QUIT', command=self.quit)
        self.quit.grid(row=3, column=1)


    def update_time(self):

        if (self.running == True):      #Clock is running

            self.timer[2] -= 1          #Count Down

            if (self.timer[2] < 0):     #if centiseconds is negative
                self.timer[2] = 100     #reset to 100 centiseconds
                self.timer[1] -= 1      #subtract 1 second

            if (self.timer[1] < 0):     #if seconds is negative
                self.timer[1] = 60      #reset to 60 seconds
                self.timer[1] -= 1      #subtract 1 second
                self.timer[0] -= 1      #subtract 1 minute

            self.timeString = str(self.timer[0]) + ':' + str(self.timer[1]) + ':' + str(self.timer[2])
            self.show.config(text=self.timeString)
        root.after(10, self.update_time)



    def addMinute(self):
        self.timer[0] += 1
        self.timeString = str(self.timer[0]) + ':' + str(self.timer[1]) + ':' + str(self.timer[2])
        self.show.config(text=self.timeString)

    def addSecond(self):
        self.timer[1] += 1
        self.timeString = str(self.timer[0]) + ':' + str(self.timer[1]) + ':' + str(self.timer[2])
        self.show.config(text=self.timeString)

    def start(self):            #Start the clock
        self.running = True
        print 'Clock Running...'

    def pause(self):            #Pause the clock
        self.running = False
        print 'Clock Paused'    

    def resetTime(self):        #Reset the clock
        self.running = False
        self.timer = [0,0,0]
        print 'Clock is Reset'  
        self.show.config(text='00:00:00')

    def quit(self):             #Quit the program
        root.destroy()



root = Tkinter.Tk()

up = CountsUp(root)
down = CountsDown(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it. I'll show you my preffered version

```
from tkinter import * #if below 3.X it's Tkinter


class Anynameyoulike(Tk): #passing Tk to the class directly, makes most sense for me
    def __init__(self): #__init__ is a special method thats get called automatically,
        Tk.__init__(self) #whenever you create an object out of this class
        #use init to make variables and call certain methods like creating UI 
        self.timer = [0,0,0] # [minutes ,seconds, centiseconds]
        #don't forget the self., so you the whole class knows this object   
        self.resizeable(0, 0) #make it resizeable to 0 pixels in width and height aka. not resizeable is what I like to do   
        self.makeui()
    def makeui(self):
        timeFrame = LabelFrame(root, text='Time Frame', width=1200)
        timeFrame.grid(row=2,column=2, sticky=W)
        #also rest of the buttons, labels I didn't bother copying
        #so on
    def start(self): #don't forget to pass in self
        global state #define it like self.state in init and no need for global
        state = True
        print 'Clock Running...'
   #define rest of the stuff needed copy/paste, adjust the object names, easy

#to finish do
anyname = Anynameyoulike()
anyname.mainloop()
```

Comment: in the class, jsut as start. Don't forget to pass in self. It doesn't matter if it's in the beggining or end, since when the compiler compiles the code, in the  begging the methods aren't used, only at the very end when we create the object anyname out of the class, which will run makeui etc... I didn't read your code so it don't know how exactly it works. Don't forget if you need to run any other methods by "default", call them in __init__

Comment: I meant 'update_time()' when I'm calling the function, not 'def update_time(self)'. Where do I call the function?

Comment: Well in the original program  you do so at the very end so put it into init after self.makeui (), since it is called automatically PS sorry for late response I knocked out myself lol

Comment: did you use self.updatetime() ? and pass in self when defining it ?